# Error matrices de confusión en R

Tags: r

Estaba haciendo algunas pruebas, esta vez con las regresiones logísticas, para seguir progresando en R. He utilizado el dataset del Titanic y todo me iba correctamente hasta que tuve que crear la matriz de confusión, de donde me salió un error que no termino de entender:

> Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.

El código correspondiente a la matriz de confusión es el siguiente:

```
#Crear la matriz de confusion
matrizconfusion<-confusionMatrix(prediccionfinal, titanic_train$Age)
```

Y el resto del código sería este:

```
## Cargar la librería titanic para poder acceder a los datasets
install.packages("titanic");library(titanic)
install.packages("caret");library(caret) #Para la representación gráfica

## Cargar los datasets
data("titanic_train")
data("titanic_test")

## Añadir columna de Supervivientes a la tabla con valores NA
titanic_test$Survived <- NA

## Combinar ambos dataset
complete_data <- rbind(titanic_train, titanic_test)

## Estructura del dataset
str(complete_data)

## Modelo logístico
x=titanic_train$Age #Edades
y=titanic_train$Survived #¿Sobrevivieron? 1=SI 0=NO
df=complete_data #dataframe que vamos a utilizar
modelo_logistico <- glm(y ~ x, data = df, family = "binomial") # family = "binomial" es necesario para decirle que use regresion logistica
print(modelo_logistico)
summary(modelo_logistico)
modelo_logistico$coefficients

predicciones=predict(modelo_logistico,
                     newdata=data.frame(x=x))
#Redondear las probabilidades de la prediccion
prediccionfinal<-as.factor(round(predicciones))
```

A ver si podéis echarme una mano (ojalá). Agradecería una breve explicación junto a la solución para entenderlo para una próxima vez :) Soy nuevo en este lenguaje así que disculpen si es un error de novato!

Answer (score 0):

Encuentro dos problemas en tu código.

1. En el argumento `reference` de la función `confusionMatrix` estás pasando el vector `Age`, que es tu variable independiente en el modelo. Por como especificas tu modelo este está tratando de predecir `Survived` como una función de `Age`, no al revés. Seguramente por eso tienes el error, porque tu modelo predice `Survived` y quieres hacer la matriz de confusión con `Age`.
2. Dado que estás trabajando un problema de clasificación para obtener la clase predicha por el modelo deberías usar `type = "response"` en el `predict`. `predict` es una función genérica que tiene métodos para muchas clases de objetos. En este caso estás usando (implícitamente) `predict.glm()`, que es el método para modelos lineales generalizados. Si te fijas con `help(predict.glm)` verás que hay 3 tipos de predicción. Por defecto (la que estás utilizando) es `link`, que te da la predicción en la escala de los predictores, que es muy complicada de entender porque es un modelo logit i.e. es un logaritmo de razón de probabilidad. De todas formas si te fijas puedes ver el signo, las predicciones negativas en esta escala son 0 en la escala de la dependiente, al revés con las positivas.

Si usas `type = "response"` te da la predicción en la escala de la variable dependiente, entonces vas a tener tus predicciones en las categorías del factor (sobrevivió/no sobrevivió).